# Rails 3.2.1: why is iterating through a hash in controller method fetching only last key-value pair?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, controller

I am trying to iterate over a hash in my **controller method**:

```
   @trsesh_counts.each do |trsesh_mode, trsesh_count|
    @hash = "#{trsesh_mode} (#{trsesh_count})"
   end
```

In my **view**, I call the instance variable @hash:

```
     <% @trsesh_counts.each do |trsesh_mode, trsesh_count| %>
            <%= "#{trsesh_mode} (#{trsesh_count})" %>
            <% end %>
        vs. <%= @hash %>    where array = <%= @trsesh_counts %>
```

which outputs the following:

```
 (7) Running (12) Weightlifting (1) vs. Weightlifting (1) where array = {""=>7, "Running"=>12, "Weightlifting"=>1}
```

why is the @hash instance variable fetching only the last key-value pair of the hash (Weightlifting (1))? How can I get @hash to output the entire hash like when I iterate in the view?

**EDIT:** for some reason I can call fetch on each key-value pair, but I still can't iterate over each pair.

```
 h = @trsesh_counts
         @hash = h.fetch("Running")
```

... returns 12, the value for the "Running" key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you are reassigning the value of `@hash` each time you loop through `@trsesh_counts`. Also, I've kept your variable names for clarity, but I'd recommend changing the name of `@hash`, as it's really a string, not a hash. Change your original code snippet to this:

```
@hash = ""
@trsesh_counts.each do |trsesh_mode, trsesh_count|
  @hash << "#{trsesh_mode} (#{trsesh_count}) "
end
```

Note the initial assignment of `@hash = ""` to an empty string, then the use of `<<` inside the each block. (I've also included a trailing space in the string value.) This will build up the value of `@hash` instead of reassigning a new value to it on each iteration.

This can also be shortened using `Enumerable#each_with_object` like so:

```
@hash = @trsesh_counts.each_with_object("") { |ary, str| str << "#{ary[0]} (#{ary[1]}) " }
```